# Outlook add-in and WPF window

Tags: wpf, interop, outlook-addin

I am writing a simple Outlook addin using addin Express. This is for 2007 and 2010 . I have a wpf window I want  to launch modally when a ribbon button is pressed in OL .
The  code I have right now just does this

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
mw.ShowDialog();
```

and everything seems to work fine. I guess my question is , is it really this easy or is something going to get me in the rear later. Is there no need for any interop of any sort here?
Thanks

Comment: Just as a comment - pay attention to use WPF in Office Solutions if your add-ins must run at client installations in Terminal Server environments. TS are still not prepared to use WPF.